# Using Image to Submit Form Issue

Tags: javascript, form-submit

I have tried several different submit buttons but can not seem to get this to work properly.

```
<form id="logForm" action="<?php $retpage; ?>" method="POST" name="logForm">
    <div>
        <table width="400px" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" class="loginform">
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td width="28%">Email:</td>
                <td width="72%">
                    <input name="usr_email" type="text" class="required" id="txtbox" size="25" value="<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['user_name'])){
            print ($_COOKIE['user_name']);
} else if(isset($_POST['usr_email'])){
            print ($_POST['usr_email']);
} else {
            print '';} ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input name="pwd" type="password" class="required password" id="txtbox" size="25"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div align="center">
                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" id="remember" value="1"> Remember me
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr> 
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div align="center"> 
                        <p><input name="doLogin" type="image" id="doLogin" value="Login" src="images/login.png" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 30px; width: 66px;" onsubmit="document.logForm.submit(); return false;" /></p>           
                        <p><a href="signup.php">Register Free</a><font color="#FF6600">|</font> <a href="forgot.php">Forgot Password</a> <font color="#FF6600"></font></p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I use the below submit button, it works prefectly, but I want to use an image to submit. The above login button does not work.

```
<input name="doLogin" type="submit" id="doLogin" value="Login">
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take out the `onsubmit` attribute and just use:

```
<input type="image" src="foo.png" />
```

This will submit the form when clicked.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/q3SN8/

Additionally, you're not printing your action:

```
action="<?php $retpage; ?>" // should be <?php echo $retpage; ?>
```

Comment: I changed it to:                 <input name="doLogin" type="image" id="doLogin" value="Login" src="images/login.png" style="vertical-align: middle; height: 30px; width: 66px;"/>   still does not submit

Comment: @DJHowarth You were also not printing out your `$retpage` variable.

Comment: if I print the variable, none of the forms will submit

Comment: @DJHowarth If you *don't* print that, the form submits to the same page it's on. What do you mean by *forms*? You have more than one? And if you don't want that value there, why do you have the variable to begin with?

Comment: forms meaning, the original form and the javascript form. There will only be the javascript form, once I get it to work properly. that variable is there for other reasons.

Comment: @DJHowarth JavaScript form? There's far too much information missing from  your question. I provided a fiddle above demonstrating the success of simply using `<input type="image" />`. If that doesn't work, it's because you have some other detail about your problem you didn't communicate.

Answer (score 1):

Or jquery:

```
<img src="images/login.png" class="submitImage">

<script>
   $(".submitImage").click(function() {
       $("#logForm").submit();      
   });
</script>
```

Ofc, put this betwen  tags of your html page:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this at the top:

```
if ($_POST['doLogin']=='Login')
```

{
php & mysql code
}

I took that out and it works fine.

My question now is, why does the javascript not Post the doLogin?

Comment: JS should post "logForm" , "doLogin" is only submit button as i can see.